# Adding Click Handler to NSTextField in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, onclick, event-handling, nstextfield

I am having trouble detecting a user's double click in swift, I want to detect when they double click on an NSTextField.

```
func someFunc() {
    y.target = self
    y.action = "editLabel:"
}

@IBAction func editLabel(obj:AnyObject?) {
    NSLog("here");
}
```

The above code doesn't work, I can't seem to find the basic documentation that shows how to add event handlers. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

I guess your text field is a label, not an editable text field in its normal state. Starting with OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), you can use [`NSClickGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSGestureRecognizer_Class/):

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let gesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer()
    gesture.buttonMask = 0x1 // left mouse
    gesture.numberOfClicksRequired = 2
    gesture.target = self
    gesture.action = "editLabel:"

    myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func editLabel(sender: NSGestureRecognizer) {
    if let label = sender.view as? NSTextField {
        print("Hello world")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same on OS X 10.9?

Comment: @IhorSkliar Have you found the solution? As this code is working fine for me in OS 10.14.4.

Although the lines could be reduced by - 


 let gesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(button_Cliecked(editLabel:)))

Answer (score 0):

A text field does not handling editing, as such. When a text field has focus, a text view is added to the window, overlapping the area of the text field. This is called the "field editor" and it is responsible for handling editing.

It seems the most likely place for you to change the behavior of a double-click is in the text storage object used by that text view. `NSTextStorage` inherits from `NSMutableAttributedString` which inherits from `NSAttributedString` which has a -`doubleClickAtIndex`: method. That method returns the range of the text that should be selected by a double-click at a particular index.

So, you'll want to implement a subclass of `NSTextStorage` that overrides that method and returns a different result in some circumstances. `NSTextStorage` is a semi-abstract base class of a class cluster. Subclassing it requires a bit more than usual. You have to implement the primitive methods of `NSAttributedString` and `NSMutableAttributedString`. See the docs about it.

There are a few places to customize the field editor by replacing its text storage object with an instance of your class:

You could implement a custom subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`. Set your text field to use this as its cell. In your subclass, override -`fieldEditorForView`:. In your override, instantiate an `NSTextView`. Obtain its layoutManager and call -`replaceTextStorage`: on that, passing it an instance of your custom text storage class. (This is easier than putting together the hierarchy of objects that is involved with text editing, although you could do that yourself.) Set the fieldEditor property of the text view to true and return it.
In your window delegate, implement -`windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject`:. Create, configure, and return an `NSTextView` using your custom text storage, as above.